# Permission to unlock the folder

Tags: permissions

I don't have a permission to open the folder, But I need to open the folder even to view the files, when I was trying I got access deny.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide the outputs of `echo $USER`, `ls -ld /path/to/the/directory/you/want/to/open`. After that, notify me with a comment here containing "@ByteCommander", please and I will tell you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo`.

To see what is inside the directory: `sudo ls [directory]`
If you want to get temporary root rights do `sudo su -`

Disclaimer: With great power comes great responsibility. As a root you can do a lot of harm to your system. Use with care.

Comment: Ok, right. Let's remove the comments.